# Can you call a function from tk.OptionMenu's command parameter without passing an argument

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to check if the user has changed any values in tkinter widgets and then prompt to save those values or lose changes.

A lot of applications have 3 buttons at the bottom right of their settings frame `OK`, `Cancel`, and `Apply` where `Apply` is disabled until a change has been made. I am imitating this feature in my program.

When I use `tk.OptionMenu(command=function)`, by default it sends the current user selection to the function, however I do not need to know the current selection because regardless of what it is, I want to prompt the user to save settings.

Running the program would result in the following error:

> TypeError: function() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

A simple workaround I thought of would be to give an arbitrary parameter to `function()` like so:

```
def function(param=None):
    value_change.status = True
```

See **Example Code** for `value_change.status` usage.

However, PyCharm points out that `param` is not used and marks it as a weak warning. I don't have any use for the passed value so I can't do much with `param` except ignore it and the PyCharm warning as well. There's technically nothing wrong here but I like seeing that green checkmark at the top right of my screen so I came up with another workaround:

```
def function(param=None):
    value_change.status = True if param else False
```

Both `param=None` and `if param else False` are redundant since they're only placeholders to make the code run smoothly and not throw any warnings.

Another problem arises when I want to use `function()` for other widget commands which do not pass arguments such as `tk.Checkbutton(command=function)` and I have to change my code to the following lines which makes the code appear even more redundant than before.

```
def function(param=True):
    value_change.status = True if param else False
```

Is there a way to not pass an argument through `tk.OptionMenu(command=function)`?

**Example Code**

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread

def value_change():
    value_change.count = 0
    value_change.status = False

    print('Has the user changed settings in the past 3 seconds?')

    while value_change.status != 'exit':
        if value_change.status:
            value_change.count += 1
            
            # Reset count if no change after 3 seconds
            if value_change.count > 3:
                value_change.count = 0
                value_change.status = False

        print(value_change.status)
        time.sleep(1)

def function(param=True):
    value_change.status = True if param else False
    value_change.count = 0


gui = tk.Tk()
gui.geometry('100x100')

"""Setup OptionMenu"""
menu_options = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']

menu_string = tk.StringVar()
menu_string.set(menu_options[0])

option_menu = tk.OptionMenu(gui, menu_string, *menu_options, command=function)
option_menu.pack()

"""Setup CheckButton"""
check_int = tk.IntVar()

check = tk.Checkbutton(gui, variable=check_int, command=function)
check.pack()

"""Turn On Thread and Run Program"""
Thread(target=value_change).start()
gui.mainloop()

"""Signal Threaded Function to Exit"""
value_change.status = 'exit'
```

The above example is a minimal reproduction, I did not include the `OK` `Cancel` `Apply` buttons and their functions as they are not necessary and would only make the code lengthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lambda`:

```
option_menu = tk.OptionMenu(gui, menu_string, *menu_options, command=lambda v: function())
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot